# Custom UITableViewCell don't react on touch

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, custom-cell

I'm hoping to create universal swipeable `SwipeableTableViewCell`. So I've some xib, and swift file with it which extend `SwipeableTableViewCell`. In `SwipeableTableViewCell` I'm adding programmatically `UIScrollView` to view and move `conetntView` to this `scrollView`. In results, I can use interface builder and add for ex. `UIButtons` to `scrollView` instead of using `UITableViewRowAction`.

This isn't entire my idea, it's based on this [code](https://github.com/blixt/SwipeableTableViewCell).

This is how it's done.

**SwipeableTableViewCell.swift**

Method that is called after `super.awakeFromNib()`

```
private func setup() {
    // Create the scroll view which enables the horizontal swiping.
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.contentView.bounds)
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth,.FlexibleHeight]

    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = false
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    self.scrollView = scrollView

    self.addSubview(scrollView)

    var contentBouds = self.contentView.bounds.size
    contentBouds.height = 0
    self.scrollView.contentSize = contentBouds
    self.backgroundColor = self.contentView.backgroundColor

    // Create the containers which will contain buttons on the left and right sides.
    self.buttonViews = [self.createButtonsView(),self.createButtonsView()]

    // Set up main content area.
    let newContentView = UIScrollView(frame:scrollView.bounds)
    newContentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth,.FlexibleHeight]
    newContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    scrollView.addSubview(newContentView)
    self.scrollViewContentView = newContentView

    self.contentView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.scrollViewContentView.addSubview(self.contentView)
}
```

**Problem**

My problem is that, after `contentView` is moved to `scrollViewContentView` then it's stop reacting on tap. I'm guessing it's because `conetntView` was removed from views hierarchy. Messing with calling `becomeFirstResponder` in `contentView`, `scrollViewContentView` or `scrollView` is not helping.

How I can make this right? Is it even possible?

### UPDATE

It's amazing how this questions works. I can struggle with problem for couple days and as soon as I post question then new traces came up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I download your repo and fix your code by adding a custom scroll-view and passing as delegate to your custom cell this is the code

```
- (void)setUp {
// Create the scroll view which enables the horizontal swiping.
SwipeableScrollView *scrollView = [[SwipeableScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.bounds.size;
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
[self.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
self.scrollView = scrollView;
self.scrollView.customDelegate = self;

//self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

// Create the containers which will contain buttons on the left and right sides.
self.buttonViews = @[[self createButtonsView], [self createButtonsView]];

// Set up main content area.
UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollView.bounds];
contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[scrollView addSubview:contentView];
self.scrollViewContentView = contentView;

// Put a label in the scroll view content area.
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(contentView.bounds, 10, 0)];
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.scrollViewContentView addSubview:label];
self.scrollViewLabel = label;

// Listen for events that tell cells to hide their buttons.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleCloseEvent:)
                                             name:kSwipeableTableViewCellCloseEvent
                                           object:nil];
```

}

I also add this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self class] closeAllCellsExcept:nil];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

This is .h of SwipeableScrollView

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SwipeableScrollView : UIScrollView

@property (weak,nonatomic) UIResponder * customDelegate;

@end
```

and this is .m

```
#import "SwipeableScrollView.h"

@implementation SwipeableScrollView


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.customDelegate touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.customDelegate touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.customDelegate touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Hope this help, I also have a pull request to your repo!

Comment: Well you do make pull request but to not mine fork :) Mine is entire rewriten in swift, at this moment not yet commited. If you don't mind before commiting I'll add your current code or I'll do commit and then you will make pull request?

Comment: If you don't mind I want to commit the solution to your fork, with some improvements in code , and I wish to became  a collaborator in your project, regards.

Comment: No, not at all. Give me 2h to commit.

Comment: @Dudi I am waiting to push my solution, regards

Comment: I see that you watching my repo, it's ready just make pull request.

Comment: I need permisions to make pull request to your fork, can you help me my commit is waiting

Comment: could you join to [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113663/room-for-dudi-and-reinier-melian) chat?